# Copy and Paste from Clipboard to URxvt

Tags: debian, urxvt, crunchbang

I use URxvt on my netbook, and I'd like to be able to paste to it from my clipboard, not only the primary buffer. Shift+Insert is fine for pasting from buffer, and selecting is fine for copying to buffer, but I'd like to not have to use those shortcuts.

I found a [perl script](https://github.com/muennich/urxvt-perls/blob/master/clipboard) that is supposed to do this, but it didn't work for pasting. It did copy to my clipboard, which was nice, but wouldn't paste into URxvt from my clipboard. I don't have a mouse, so middle click to paste into other applications from buffer is annoying (I remapped it to shift+ins, but still annoying). That's solved with the copying out, but doesn't solve the pasting in.

Anyone know what I can do?

Comment: This is one of the two reasons I switched from `urxvt` to `Konsole` (which supports Ctrl+Shift+C & Ctrl+Shift+V).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a clipboard manager like parcellite to sync the buffers. I don't know if this is an option for you or already to extravagant seeing that you use urxvt.

Comment: Syncing the buffers isn't a good solution, unfortunately. I've recently upgraded to debian testing, though, so I'll be trying a few other things again. I've gotten used to the moving mouse to the cursor/keeping over window deal.

Answer (score 8):

- To paste the PRIMARY selection use the middle mouse button or shift+insert.
- To paste from the CLIPBOARD use Meta (Alt) + middle mouse button.